# Can I change a textbox value and hit submit on a random site via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

There is a site on which I'd like to automatically populate a value in a textbox and then submit it. The site is not run by me.

Is this doable via GAS?

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to do on gas. Gas is not for that.